# Active Record where join table record doesn't exist

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to get a list of all records that don't exist in a join table.

The models are User, Game and MarkedGame, where users can mark games as played. It's a many to many relationship:

```
User > MarkedGame < Game
```

What I want is a list of all games that **haven't** been marked by the user.

I know that I could do two separate queries and subtract them:

```
Game.all - current_user.games
```

But I don't like that this leaves me with an array rather than an Active Record relation object. Plus it seems like there should be a more performant way of doing it.

If there is no Active Record way of handling this, is there perhaps a SQL way? My raw SQL is not particularly strong so any help on that would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should do it. Returns all games that have not been marked by the current user.

```
Game.where('id not in (select game_id from marked_games where user_id = ?)', current_user.id)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

So is this basically saying where the game id is not in a subquery of game ids?

Comment: Yes, and it is only one query, so it's quite fast if you have the correct indexes in your db.

Comment: Great, thanks again. The other answer by potashin also works perfectly, do you have an opinion on which is the better solution?

Comment: Well, you will have to decide that I think. Mine runs in one query, while the other first has to run the inner query. It just depends on which one you prefer I think.

Comment: @Iceman: it is not exactly accurate, both run at least two queries, but in my example they are separate and in yours they are nested. So it is hard to say, at least for me, which query it better.

Comment: @potashin That is what I meant, it's easier for the query optimizer to optimize one query. But I'm not gonna fight over that, these are both good solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion around this guys, I marked Iceman's correct in the end but both seemed to work great

Answer (score 10):

You can try the following:

```
Game.where.not(id: MarkedGame.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:game_id))
```

Comment: Also works perfectly, thanks! Do you have an opinion on whether yours is better or worse than the one above? Trying to figure out which one to mark as the answer